# Hidden Link through JS or AJAX

Tags: javascript, links

Is there a way to hide a URL behind JavaScript? I want to place ads where the GET URL isn't obvious.

I'm thinking that perhaps some JS or AJAX can take the brunt of the work to forward the user. I want to hide the ultimate location to keep bots and the sort (even users' immediate eyes) away from the target page.

Comment: You want users to click a link, having no idea where it will take them?

Comment: They are clicking on an ad.  I don't want my system scraped.  Here is a confusing ad link, that is still scrapeable. `https://www.gotrack1.es/?flux_fts=xqplxaazztqcziptzqeqccilocxiiotaxiaaz58a89&flux_cost=0.005&click_id=8484995d-fcbc-4307-b997-ca8c96b98e0d&campaign_id=1303&category_id=&adspot_id=225&creative_id=8774&keywords=%7B+keywords+%7D&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.liveleak.com%2Fview%3Ft%3DuukWU_1530623662&site_host=liveleak.com&site_id=103&carrier=`

Comment: It sounds like you want a short link like you would get from bit.ly (for example)...